# SQL Date operations

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, date

In a table I have got a two dates BidDate that is like: '05/03/2015 15:44' and EndDate that is in format '08/03/2015'.

What I would like to get is average bid based on number of dates before EndDate in whole number. So like when EndData = '08/03/2015' and BidDate='05/03/2015 15:44' the value would be 3 and not something like 03/01/1900 11:14:08.

```
SELECT Enddate-BidDate as DBE, AVG(CurrencyAmount)

FROM transactions ts

WHERE BidID = '12345'
GROUP BY Enddate-BidDate
ORDER BY 1
```

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Comment: What database are you using?  SQL Server and MySQL are very different databases.

Comment: Does "number of dates" mean "number of days/months/years"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have stored the values as date/time values in the database (instead of strings), then you can use `datediff()` in either database.  The syntax is a little different.

In SQL Server:

```
select datediff(day, BidDate, EndDate)
```

In MySQL:

```
select datediff(EndDate, BidDate)
```

If they are stored as strings, then you should fix your database structure so dates are stored in native format.  Barring that, you can convert them, but the conversion code is highly database dependent.